# Django Rest DRF : getting count of objects for reverse relation

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, reverse

Let's say I have two models.

> Model

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    # other fields

class ItemRelation(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='relations_item')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='relations_user')
    has_viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_loved = models.BooleanFields(default=False)
```

Now, what I want to do is I want to get the view_count and love_count for all items using django rest api.

> views.py

```
class ItemView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Items.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch('relations_item',
            queryset=ItemRelation.objects.filter(Q(has_viewed=True) | Q(has_loved=True))
            )
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

Well, this was the plan but I have absolutely no idea how to get the view_count and love_count for each item in the list-api-view. I tried quite a few things on my serializer but I don't think it's going to work.
I can however use SerializerMethod() to do the work, but that would go through the DB N+1 number of times. I have read through the docs along with a few other blogs for prefetch_related and I was able to do things easily until this count problem showed up.

Just a sample from my serializer.

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['name', 'relations_item']
```

Comment: `prefetch_related` is not the right tool here; you don't care about the actual related object, you just want the counts. You need [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset).

Comment: i want to do it with the least db hits. if I use count then my api hits the db twice for each item. I still couldn't figure out how to properly use annotate, I only get a true or null value depending on whether the exp was viewed or loved by someone - as long as one person viewed or loved it i get true. Pretty sure I am doing something wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to count the number of relations in which a) `has_viewed==True` and b) `has_loved==True`.

That should be possible by using `annotate()` with [Django Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/):

```py
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Sum, When


class ItemView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Items.objects.annotate(
                   view_count=Sum(
                       When(relations_item__has_viewed=True, then=1),
                       output_field=IntegerField(),
                   ),
                   love_count=Sum(
                       When(relations_item__has_loved=True, then=1),
                       output_field=IntegerField(),
                   ),
               )
    # ...
```

Comment: ahh... so I was supposed to use the annotate in views, i was trying to do the same in serializers file :D Thanks